# QGIS 2.0.1. missing Google Mercator CRS

Tags: qgis, google-maps, coordinate-system

I've downloaded the latest QGIS version and I cannot add basemap. I installed OpenLayers plugin and while adding any map from list QGIS crashes. I tried to enable Google Mercator CRS first, yet it's not in the list of available CRSs. Does anybody know how to fix this and how can start adding basemaps? Or is it possible to add National Geographic map as a basemap?

Comment: You should probably use the QuickMapServices plugin instead: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123227/google-maps-openlayer-plugin-not-zooming-in-or-panning?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3):

The Openlayers plugin is depending on EPSG:3857.

In QGIS 2.0.1, this is called `WGS84 / Pseudo Mercator`.

It is not necessary to set the CRS in advance, the plugin changes the CRS on its own if necessary. Enabeling On-the-fly reprojection might prevent crashing, or preloading some vector data from your part of the world.

Comment: Thanks, I've found Pseudo Mercator. Yet it crashes anyway, even if "on-the-fly" is enabled. And how do I preload some vector data from particular part of the world?

Comment: If you don't have any from previous projects, Natural Earth offers vector data for the whole world. As an alternative to Openlayers, you can try the new TileLayer Plugin. You just have to investigate how the config file has to be written.

Answer (score 0):

In case a projection is missing for you could always add it yourself as custom projection. Just go to "Settings" -> "Custom CRS" and create your own.

For google mercator:

```
+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0
+k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs
```

Although i believe that GoogleMercator is somewhere in the available CRS list.