# Google Maps OpenLayers plugin not zooming in or panning

Tags: google, qgis-openlayers-plugin

So recently I've noticed that the OpenLayers plugin for Google Maps (Google satellite, physical etc) is not allowing me to zoom into the specific area I require. Every time I try and zoom it pans back to the global view.

I have upgraded the plugin to its latest version and on QGIS 2.6 Brighton. It only seems to happen on the Google Maps, but not on the others (e.g. Bing). Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122951/using-google-maps-plugin-in-qgis. See also http://hub.qgis.org/issues/6822

Comment: I have the excactly same error! It worked still two days ago. Is there any help for this?

Comment: I don't have enough rep to post an answer, but this is a known bug, tracked at https://hub.qgis.org/issues/11728 Maybe leaving a comment there, or "watching" the issue, will help raise its priority for fixing.

Answer (score 1):

Use the QuickMap Services plugin instead. It works well and doesn't have the issues that were reported in Print Composer. [See this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121752/why-i-cannot-export-osm-map-as-a-pdf-jpeg-in-qgis-2-4/225012#225012)

Answer (score 0):

I was using 2.2 until today and it started happening there. I uninstalled 2.2 and installed 2.6 hoping that would fix it. It did not. 2.6 said that the Openlayers plugin I had from 2.2 was not supported. I clicked the button to "Reinstall plugin". That didn't work either. Then I clicked "Uninstall plugin" and then "Install plugin". IT WORKED!

Comment: When you say it worked, do you mean that you were able to add a Google map, and zoom in/out, and the Google basemap would zoom correctly with the other layers?